# Hair particles bunching around the edge of a weight painting

Tags: hair

[image]

Hi!

I'm trying to put fur onto this teddy bear, and I have this weird bunching problem around the nose and feet (see image). The bear is one mesh with a weight paint deciding where the hairs should be placed (on the body, not the nose). However, the hairs look huge around the edge of the weight painting. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Your particles seem to be waaay too thick all round. You can only see it around the nose because it is a boundary area.

Comment: I agree with Duarte. Check/adjust the settings under *Hair Shape*.